# How can I set a context value on request for my middleware? Getting go-staticcheck issues

Tags: go

Here's my `ErrorHandler` which is a middleware that wraps my other handlers -

```
func ErrorHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)

        if err, ok := r.Context().Value(auth.ErrorContextKey).(error); ok && err != nil {
            switch e := err.(type) {
            case *app.AppError:
                w.WriteHeader(e.Status)
                render.JSON(w, r, e)
                return
            default:
                internalErr := app.NewInternalError("internal-error", "Something went wrong", nil)
                w.WriteHeader(internalErr.Status)
                render.JSON(w, r, internalErr)
                return
            }
        }
    })
}
```

In my other handlers, I have been trying to add the error to the context, but I get some issues. Here's an example snippet

```
func (h *Http) signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var params dto.SignUpDTO
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    if err := decoder.Decode(&params); err != nil {
        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), auth.ErrorContextKey, app.NewBadRequestError("auth/invalid-signup-params", "invalid email or password", err))
        r = r.WithContext(ctx)
        return
    }

}
```

I get an issue on the `r = r.WithContext(ctx)`:

> this value of r is never used (SA4006)go-staticcheck

> WithContext doesn't have side effects and its return value is ignored (SA4017)go-staticcheck

Comment: `r2 := r.WithContext(ctx)`; `*r = *r2`

Comment: thanks. that works! is there a cleaner way to do this? or something better you could recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to write a comment but it was too long, so here I go:

About OP's question if there is a way of doing that in a cleaner way:
The cleaner way is simply don't do it. Since it's kind of a bad practice for a method to "know" that there is a decorator/middleware above it.

Instead, you can do a shared method for rendering error

```golang
func (h *HTTP) renderError(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
            switch e := err.(type) {
            case *app.AppError:
                w.WriteHeader(e.Status)
                render.JSON(w, r, e)
                return
            default:
                internalErr := app.NewInternalError("internal-error", "Something went wrong", nil)
                w.WriteHeader(internalErr.Status)
                render.JSON(w, r, internalErr)
                return
            }

}
```

In middleware, you can log/trace/recover from panic/authentication etc, the idea of a middleware is that you add functionality, that the "inner" handler shouldn't really know or care about. Here your handlers know about the middleware simply because they are doing this line:

```golang
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), auth.ErrorContextKey, app.NewBadRequestError("auth/invalid-signup-params", "invalid email or password", err))
r = r.WithContext(ctx)
```

Instead you can just do:

```golang
    if err := decoder.Decode(&params); err != nil {
        h.renderError(w, r, err)
        return
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Oren. BTW for other folks who read this, maybe you're using go-chi/render as well.

Instead of `w.WriteHeader(..status code..)` use `render.Status(w, ..status code..)`